# Parent div extending the end of page - need to fit contents

Tags: css, html

The parent div is extending to the bottom of the page for some reason. I'm trying to get it to have a height of it's contents.

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu" >
    <ul class="bmenu">
        <li onclick="wideScreen()">Wide Screen</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li onclick="randFrame()">Random Border</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li onclick="randBG()">Control Bar</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sideMenu{
    position: fixed;
    left: -90px;
    top: 250px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid #999400;
    z-index:1000000;
    float:left;
    display:table;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: whats the question here? ofcourse parent div will extend if the child elements with content increases..

Comment: It's extending way past the 3 list items and reaching the bottom of the wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#sideMenu` is extending to the bottom of the page because it has `height:100%`. This means that the height of the div will be calculated with respect to the height of the containing block (in this case, probably `body`). If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the value will be computed as `auto`. [More info on the `height` property can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height).

To solve your issue, simply remove `height:100%` from the CSS. That way, `#sideMenu` will only extend to the height of its contents (in your case, the list items).

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rZtyB/)

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I don't think I understand height 100%.

Comment: @Batman I added more info about the `height` property and percentages. Hope this helped! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Batman If I solved your problem, please upvote and/or accept this as the answer. That way others who run into the same problem in the future will know this solution works.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you very much for your help. Everything looks good now. Thanks!